# Moving a middle initial from the end of a name to the middle

Tags: java, regex

I have fields that contain a name in the following format: First Last (Middle Initial). Not all fields have the middle initial and the middle initial sometimes has a period, sometimes it doesn't. I need to put the middle initial before the last name.

ex. `John Smith f.` needs to be `John f. Smith`

Possible iterations of a name include:

- John Smith
- John Smith F
- John Smith F.
- John Smith f
- John Smith f.

Comment: can it be assumed space separates the names?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @gtgaxiola Yes they're separated by spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split on whitespace `\s+`

If you don't have three parts then you know there is no middle name

```
String[] names = original.split("\\s+");
if(names.length == 3) {
   String newName = names[0] + " " + names[2] + " " + names[1];
}
```

Testing in a main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    name.add("John Smith");
    name.add("John Smith F.");
    name.add("John Smith f");
    name.add("John Smith-Wesson F.");
    for (String original : name) {
        String[] names = original.split("\\s+");
        if (names.length == 3) {
            System.out.println(names[0] + " " + names[2] + " " + names[1]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(original);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still using a regex (just a very simple one in this case), since [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) takes a regex as a `String` as its argument.